# Updating the GPS position of a device in an Android app

Tags: android, kotlin, geolocation, google-play-services, android-gps

I have a tiny Android app written in kotlin, it gets the location of the device. All the code is below. I am following this document https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates in order to implement updating the GPS position. But I only get the lastLocation once.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
    lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        gpsPermissionCheck()

        val client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

        client.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->
            location?.let {
                println("We now have the location!")
                println("Latitude:"+it.latitude.toString()+"   Longitude:"+it.longitude.    toString())
                val compoID = resources.getIdentifier("txtlabel","id",packageName)
                val theLabel = findViewById<TextView>(compoID)
                theLabel.text = "Latit: "+it.latitude.toString()+"   Longit:"+it.longitude. toString()
            }
        }

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
            interval = 10000
            fastestInterval = 5000
            //priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        }

        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
                locationResult ?: return
                for (location in locationResult.locations){
                    // Update UI with location data
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }
    }


    fun gpsPermissionCheck() {
        try {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    applicationContext,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                    101
                )
            } else {
                //locationStart()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    } /* End of gpsPermissionCheck */
}
```

When I add the block of code:

```
locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {...}
```

I get this error message:

```
'onLocationResult' overrides nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Answer

Step1:

Add manifest permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Step2:

Add your activity

```
companion object{
    private const val UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000L
    private const val FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
        UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2
}
private lateinit var  mFusedLocationClient :FusedLocationProviderClient
```

init client onCreate function

```
mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
```

Step3:

Create this callback on the top

```
private val mCallBack = object: LocationCallback(){
    override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLocationResult: $p0")
        super.onLocationResult(p0)
    }

    override fun onLocationAvailability(p0: LocationAvailability) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLocationAvailability: $p0")
        super.onLocationAvailability(p0)
    }

}
```

Step4:

Create location updates

```
private fun createLocationRequest() = LocationRequest.create().apply {
       interval = UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS
       fastestInterval = FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS
       priority = Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun requestLocationUpdates() {
    try {
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
            createLocationRequest(),
            mCallBack, Looper.myLooper()
        )
    } catch (ex: SecurityException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Lost location permission. Could not request updates. $ex")
    }
}
```

Step5:

REQUEST RUN TIME PERMISSION

Permission succeed call this method

```
requestLocationUpdates()
```

Step6:

When you want to stop call this method

```
private fun removeLocationUpdates() {
    try {
        mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mCallBack)

    } catch (ex : SecurityException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Lost location permission. Could not remove updates. $ex")
    }
}
```

Comment: The page link  below you can see few samples.

Comment: How is this code meant to be used? What is locationCallback? What is Looper?
I tried the code but with no success. I need a usage sample.

Comment: Where do see sample code (few samples?) Which link do you mean?
I looked at https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates but did not see many samples.

Comment: I added some information to my post hoping it will make it easier to get some help.

Comment: See in the bottom of the link

Comment: Yes, that's right; there is some code. But it does not work for me. I will have to update my post or write another one to tell precisely what my problem is.

Comment: I edited the post to match my current state.

Comment: It's looks good... Can you share location lib version... I'll confirm what's the problem there

Comment: I see: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0' in the dependencies. Let me know if this is not what you are asking for.

Comment: I updated my answer follow like this. Definitely it'll work

Comment: I followed your answer and yes it works. Nevertheless I do not see which step in your method makes the problem of "'onLocationResult' overrides nothing" disappear. You miraculously bring a working solution (this is great!), but I wonder how I could have found it, just starting from the document I was using. Do you have anything in particular to point out and say "this was the main mistake"?

Comment: Better said, I have a hard time to see exactly what the difference is between what I did and what you do, that makes the "'onLocationResult' overrides nothing" disappear in your case.

Comment: IDK. Your code looks good... Cache or something.       You shared implementation part only. May be somewhere mistaken

Comment: You must init callback earlier..