# show the current position of the user on google maps with a marker and the positions of different stations received from the server

Tags: android, position, google-maps-markers

hello everyone I am doing a university project and I have to show on google maps the railway stations received from the Server (with a marker and PolylineOptions) and the current position of the user (with a marker). The problem is showing the user's current location (the problem is the code shown in ** bold). My code is:

```
public class MapsLine extends Fragment {
    private String sid_user;
    private int did;
    GoogleMap map;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 0;
    Location currentLocation;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps_line, container, false);
       **SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
     fetchLocation();**
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                map = mMap;
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("I am here!");
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 5));
                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                mMap.clear(); 
                PolylineOptions polyline1 = new PolylineOptions();
                List<LatLng> routeArray = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                JSONObject requestParam = new JSONObject();
                String GET_STATIONS = "https://helpme.php";
                try {
                    requestParam.put("did", did);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(
                        Request.Method.POST,
                        GET_STATIONS,
                        requestParam,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                try {
                                    JSONArray stations_array = response.getJSONArray("stations");
                                    Log.d("main_activity_sid_map", stations_array.toString());
                                    Log.d("main_activity_sid_map", String.valueOf(stations_array.length()));
                                    for (int j = 0; j < stations_array.length(); j++) {
                                        JSONObject stations = stations_array.getJSONObject(j);
                                        String name = stations.getString("sname");
                                        String lat = stations.getString("lat");
                                        String lon = stations.getString("lon");
                                        Log.d("main_activity_sid_map", name);
                                        Log.d("main_activity_sid_map", lat);
                                        Log.d("main_activity_sid_map", lon);
                                        polyline1.add(new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(lat),Float.parseFloat(lon)));
                                        
                                        polyline1.color(Color.RED);

                                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(lat), Float.parseFloat(lon));
                                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker in " + name));
                                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                                        LatLng from_Latlng = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(lat), Float.parseFloat(lon));
                                        if (!routeArray.contains(latLng)) {
                                            routeArray.add(latLng);
                                        }
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    return;
                                }

                                drawLine(routeArray);
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            }
                        });
                MainActivity.requestQueue.add(req);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    **private void fetchLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }
        Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    currentLocation = location;
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), currentLocation.getLatitude() + "" + currentLocation.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getParentFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                    assert supportMapFragment != null;
                    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) MapsLine.this);
                }
            }
        });
    }**

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
                case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION:
                    // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // permission was granted
                        Log.d("Location", "Now the permission is granted");
                    } else {
                        // permission was not granted
                        Log.d("Location", "Permission still not granted");
                    }
                    break;
        }
    }
    
    public void drawLine(List<LatLng> points) {
        if (points == null) {
            Log.e("Draw Line", "got null as parameters");
            return;
        }
       
        Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().color(Color.RED));
        line.setPoints(points);
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
       
    }
}
```

My code does not start. How can I implement the current position of the user and the positions of the stations, received from the server?

Comment: One problem with your logic is if permissions are requested the code continues and attempts to get the map which on completion assumes `currentLocation` is set (which it would not be).  Can you advise if permissions have been granted?  Also find and post any stack trace for your app in the LogCat window.  To make progress (although not a final solution) is to initialize `currentLocation` to (0,0) or some default location.  You'll have to arrange your logic to not proceed with location operations until permission is granted.

Comment: Even if permissions are granted (avoiding the previous logic error) you still have a race condition between the `onMapReady` callback event and the location request callback `onSuccess`.  You will not be able to use `currentLocation` for any useful purpose until the `onSuccess` is called with a non-null result.  Btw in the code posted you never set `fusedLocationProviderClient` which results in a null-pointer exception.  The stack trace will always be helpful so learn to find it and post-it or learn to understand what it is saying.

Comment: Try this,
Add Google loction lib in your gradle then follow this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72790563/updating-the-gps-position-of-a-device-in-an-android-app/72791458?noredirect=1#comment128604894_72791458